# Consistency of linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Ax = B$ be a system of linear equations, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $x, B$ are $n \times 1$ vectors. Yesterday in class our teacher said that if det$A = 0$ and Adj$A.B = O$ (where Adj denotes the adjugate of $A$ and $O$ is the zero matrix of $n \times n$ order), then the system is always consistent. However, I am having trouble trying to justify this statement on my own. Is this statement true at all, and if yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm just ignorant but what is $O$ here?  Is it the $0$ vector?  A unit vector?